# Which should I use: mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, mysql

In other people's code I see both being used. So when retrieving database records, which should be used and when?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysql_fetch_array() is more generic than mysql_fetch_assoc(), although it can generate the exact same results using proper parameters.

However, if you only need an associative array, I would advise you to use the latter, as the former makes the code more ambiguous or heavy, depending on how you use it.

Answer (score 1):

just a note:

there are some other functions to get the results of your query like:

- mysql_fetch_row and
- mysql_fetch_object

Felix